# Architecture to create ACL in OpenERP

Tags: odoo

After going thru most of the OpenERP 7.0 docs I have yet to find a clear way to understand **best practices** of how to setup ACL in OpenERP.

I need to setup an architecture that will allow me to create different users that can access different levels of functionality and data. The idea is to have these groups layered in so we can easily extend functionality as we roll them in.

Is there a guide somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some docs on the OpenERP site but the concepts are reasonably simple.

1. There are a number of groups set up with the core modules that have varying levels of access (accountant vs finance manager etc.)
2. If you are writing your own modules, you create the groups and set the access rights for this as part of your module so when it is installed, this is set up.

The basic concepts are...

1. Users belong to one or more groups.
2. Groups are flat, that is there is no cascading so it pays to think carefully about your groups (e.g. accountant vs finance manager).
3. Groups have access to various parts of the system and the models.  So, typically only people in the various sales groups can see sales orders.
4. Groups can be given some or all of the CRUD options.
5. Finally there are basic security rules.  These allow you to enforce things such as only allowing a sales representative to see their own orders.

All the security settings are available under the Settings menu.  I generally find that the security system in OpenERP is good for our clients but I haven't yet had too set up a really complex, multi-layered security model for a client.